# Calculate the distance $d_{\mathcal{H}}(X_n,X):=\mathbb{E}\left(\int_0^{\infty}(X_n(t)-X(t))^2dt\right)$ for all $n\ge 1$

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

I have done this exercise but I have done something wrong because I don't get the correct result for the next part of this exercise (this is part B).

I posted something earlier that is related to another part of this exercise, but I will put all of the information in this post again. I would really appreciate it if you could help me since I have done something wrong -  I will comment at the end on what I think I did wrong. Thanks a lot!

**QUESTION:**

Let $W(t)$, $t\in\mathbb{R}_+$ be a Brownian motion with its natural filtration $\mathcal{F}_t, t\in\mathbb{R}_+$. Let
$$\mathcal{H}:=\{h(t):h(t)\text{ is an adapted process, }\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^{\infty}h^2(t)dt\right]<\infty\}$$
denote the set of general integrands with respect to $W(t)$.

Consider the stochastic processes
$$X_n(t):=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}W\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\mathbb{1}_{\left(\frac{k}{n},\frac{k+1}{n}\right]}(t), t\ge 0,$$
for $n\ge 1$ and define $X(t):=W(t)\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(t),t\ge 0$.

**D)**

**(i)** Evaluate $\mathbb{E}\left(\left[W\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)-W(t)\right]^2\right)$ for all $t\in\left(\frac{k}{n},\frac{k+1}{n}\right]$, using the definition of Brownian motion.

**(ii)** Calculate the distance of $X_n(t)$ from $X(t)$ in H, i.e.
$$d_{\mathcal{H}}(X_n,X):=\mathbb{E}\left(\int_0^{\infty}(X_n(t)-X(t))^2dt\right),$$
for all $n\ge 1$.

**(iii)** Show that $d_{\mathcal{H}}(X_n,X)\to 0,\quad n\to\infty$

**ATTEMPT:**

In parts B and C I proved that $X_n\in\mathcal{H}$ and $X\in\mathcal{H}$.

Someone on stackexchange helped me with part D(i) and the answer for this and my attempt at part D(ii) are:

**D(i)**
$$\mathbb{E}\left(\left[W\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)-W(t)\right]^2\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(\left[W\left(\frac{k}{n}-t\right)\right]^2\right)=\frac{k}{n}-t$$

**D(ii)**
We have
$$d_{\mathcal{H}}(X_n,X)=\mathbb{E}\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}(X_n(t)-X(t))^2dt\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{\frac{k}{n}}^{\frac{k+1}{n}}\left(\frac{k}{n}-t\right)dt=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left[\frac{k}{n}t-\frac{t^2}{2}\right]_{\frac{k}{n}}^{\frac{k+1}{n}}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}-\frac{1}{2n^2}=-\frac{1}{2n}$$
But how can the distance be negative? Although this satisfies $d_{\mathcal{H}}(X_n,X)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, the same method I used does not satisfy part E so it must be wrong.

What did I do wrong? My guess is the limits of the integration? The limits for $X(k/n)$ are $t\in\left(\frac{k}{n},\frac{k+1}{n}\right)$ and for $X(t)$ it is $t\in[0,1]$

Answer (score 3):

The sign in the first part of your solution is wrong. Note that you consider the case $\frac{k}{n} < t$, so the expectation is equal to $t - \frac{k}{n}$.

Comment: Thanks! Looking at the help I had got from someone else on stackexchange, he said that result... but I did not know why that was the case so I made a mistake while writing it (it seems so obvious now though -_-). I will calculate everything again and post it as a comment.

Comment: As far as I see there is no need to calculate everything again. If you fix the sign the rest of the calculations is correct.